# How to add Product ParentId into LineItems using a Service

Tags: php, symfony, shopware

I’m trying to build this page for my Website:

[image]

I need to add Products ParentId into LineItems and use twig to seperate the products with same parent id,
I’m doing that because LineItems with variation does’nt have anything in common. see the Image:

[image]

What i have done to make this page since:
1.i’ve make a Service and i’m trying to add products ParentId to LineItems
2. use $lineitems->setPayloadValue(„myVar“, $ParentId); to add ParentId into LineItems

Here is my Code:

```
use HashContext;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Event\BeforeLineItemAddedEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\Events\ProductListingResultEvent;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\Entity\SalesChannelRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Content\Product\ProductEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepositoryInterface;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;

class AddDataToPage implements EventSubscriberInterface
{   

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [BeforeLineItemAddedEvent::class => 'onLineItemAdded'];
}

/**
 * @param onLineItemAdded $event
 * @throws \Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Exception\InvalidPayloadException
 */
public function onLineItemAdded(BeforeLineItemAddedEvent $event)
{   
    $mylineitems = $event->getCart()->getLineItems();

    ## 
    #
    ##// Get parent entities
    #$criteria = new Criteria($entities);
    # $parents = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $ProductEntity);
    # echo "<pre>";
    # var_dump($parents);
    #echo "</pre>";

    #// Assign parents to variants
   # foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    #    if ($entity->getParentId() && $parents->has($entity->getParentId())) {
    #        $entity->setParent($parents->get($entity->getParentId()));
    #    }
    #} 
    ##
    ##
    ##


    $lineitems = $event->getLineItem();
   
    $lineitems->setPayloadValue("myVar", $ParentId);
  }

 }
```

I have also tried to get LineItems Parentid using Criteria & ProductEntity but unfortunately it didn’t worked.

Does anyone has an idea how to do that?
THANKS

I tried this too:

```
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\LineItem\CartDataCollection;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\CartProcessorInterface;

class AddDataToPage implements CartProcessorInterface
{
public function process(CartDataCollection $data, Cart $original, Cart $toCalculate, SalesChannelContext $context, CartBehavior $behavior):void
{
    foreach ($lineItems as $lineItem) {
        /** @var SalesChannelProductEntity $product */
        $product = $data->get('product' . $lineItem->getReferencedId()); 
        $lineItem->setPayloadValue('myVar', $product->getParentId());   
    }

}
}
```

and in my Services.xml:

```
<service id="***\Service\AddDataToPage" public="true">
        <tag name="shopware.cart.processor" priority="5100"/>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the code below and it worked prefcetly:

```
    /**
    * @var EntityRepositoryInterface
    */
    private $productRepository;


    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
    return [BeforeLineItemAddedEvent::class => 'onLineItemAdded'];
    }


    /**
    * @param onLineItemAdded $event
    * @throws \Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\Exception\InvalidPayloadException
    */
    public function onLineItemAdded(BeforeLineItemAddedEvent $event)
    {
    $mylineitems = $event->getCart()->getLineItems();
    $badlineitem = $event->getLineItem();
    $lineitems = $event->getLineItem();



    foreach ($mylineitems as $actualones) {
        
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', $actualones->getId()));
        $criteria->setLimit(2);
        $products = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $event->getContext()); 
        
        foreach ($products as $prost) {
            if($prost->getParentId() !== null) {
                $lineitems->setPayloadValue("parentId", $prost->getParentId());
            }          
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to use Shopware Cart Processor for that. Inside `process` method you can loop by your items and add any data to payload

```
foreach ($lineItems as $lineItem) {
        /** @var SalesChannelProductEntity $product */
        $product = $data->get('product-' . $lineItem->getReferencedId()); 
        $lineItem->setPayloadValue('myVar', $product->getParentId());   
    }
```

Comment: hi, and thanks for the fast answer but witch file do you mean? and how can i add my custom method to a shopware core? can you please tell me excatly how can i do that? thank you

Comment: No, no core changes) You need to create your own class which implements `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Cart\CartProcessorInterface` and implements everything inside `process()` method.  Then you need to register your own Cart processor in service container with tag `<tag name="shopware.cart.processor" priority="5100"/>` And process method will be called by Shopware core.

Comment: I have shared my code above, can you please tell me what's wrong with it? how should i implement it? thank you

Comment: Your code looks good, except that row `$product = $data->get('product' . $lineItem->getReferencedId());`. You should add dash at the and of 'product' prefix to have `$product = $data->get('product-' . $lineItem->getReferencedId());`

What is your current state now?
Do you have exception or don't get a value or...???